# How to run a Kafka-Connect SInk in standalone mode

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I would like to run a kafka connect sink in standalone mode for testing purposes, because in spite of having a beefy computer I don't want to overwork it unnecessarily...

I have this configuration in a docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka
    ports:
      - "9094:9094"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=A370i42nQuCtnpFN-7I41Q
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=BROKER://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,CLIENT://:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,BROKER:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=BROKER://:9092,CLIENT://localhost:9094
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=true # Disable in production
      # SSL Config
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=BROKER
      - BITNAMI_DEBUG=True
    volumes:
      - './ssl/kafka.keystore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks:ro'
      - './ssl/kafka.truststore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks:ro'
    networks:
      - kafka-connect

  schema-registry:
    image: bitnami/schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKA_BROKERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
    volumes:
      - './ssl/kafka.keystore.jks:/opt/bitnami/schema-registry/certs/schema-registry.keystore.jks:ro'
      - './ssl/kafka.truststore.jks:/opt/bitnami/schema-registry/certs/schema-registry.truststore.jks:ro'
    networks:
      - kafka-connect

  kafka-connect-sink:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base
    container_name: kafka-connect-sink
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8084:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-sink-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-sink-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-sink-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-sink-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect-sink"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/'
    volumes:
      - "./ssl/:/var/private/ssl/"
      - "./kafka-connect-sa-key.json:/var/private/keys/kafka-connect-sa-key.json:ro"
      - "./connect-standalone.properties:/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties"
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        # Export variable to avoid prompts during plugin installation
        export CONFLUENT_FORCE_BOOTSTRAP=true
        
        # Install Google Cloud Storage connector
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-gcs:latest
        
        # -----------
        # Launch the Kafka Connect worker
        #/etc/confluent/docker/run connect-standalone /etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties & 
        /etc/confluent/docker/run &
        # Don't exit
        sleep infinity
    networks:
      - kafka-connect

networks:
  kafka-connect:
    driver: bridge
    name: kafka-connect
```

I tried fiddling around a little bit, but to no luck unfortunately... Eventually I have to fall back on creating 3 brokers and spin up the whole this in a distributed fashion.

Is there a way to spin up a sink connector in a standalone mode? Meaning, can I specify the connector to only replicate its internal partitions once?

This is the configuration I am setting for the sink connector:

- The one that works, I am specifying three brokers

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   http://localhost:8084/connectors/gcs-sink-connector/config \
   -d '{
      "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka-1:9092,kafka-2:9092,kafka-3:9092",
      "name": "gcs-sink-connector",
      "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector",
      "tasks.max": "1",
      "gcs.bucket.name": "kafka-connect-pipeline",
      "gcs.credentials.path": "/var/private/keys/kafka-connect-sa-key.json",
      "topics": "mysql.database.students",
      "flush.size": "3",
      "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
      "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.gcs.format.json.JsonFormat",
      "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.gcs.storage.GcsStorage",
      "locale": "en_US",
      "timezone": "UTC"
   }'
```

- The one that doesn't work I am only specifying one broker:

```
...
"confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka-1:9092",
...
```

The latter causes this error:

```
ERROR [gcs-sink-connector|worker] WorkerConnector{id=gcs-sink-connector} Error while starting connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:198)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: License topic could not be created
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Unable to replicate the partition 3 time(s): The target replication factor of 3 cannot be reached because only 1 broker(s) are registered
```

I've looked at the confluent documentation, but it is not specified how to do it in a container, I've tried customizing the launch at this entry in the `command:` section

> /etc/confluent/docker/run standalone-mode  & sleep infinity

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While possible (you'd use `connect-standalone` not `standalone-mode`), there's no reason to really do so

That container is meant to be ran with `connect-distributed` and it's mostly the same codebase for both modes therefore will not "overload" your machine

You've already defined the config storage and offset topics with one replica. For the license topic, it defaults to 3 replicas, but [can be overridden](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.5/connect/references/allconfigs.html#override-default-configuration-properties) as well.

You don't need 3 brokers to run Connect. For example https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: okay, but how come when I launch specifically a sink connector specifying only one broker I get the error: 'Cannot create Library topic because 3 brokers are needed and you only registered 1 broker(s)'? What does it mean by registering a broker?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the connector config and more of the error? Also show your broker config since your question never mentions Library topic

Comment: I've added more information, if it is of any use let me know. Thank you!

Comment: License not Library :) https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.5/connect/references/allconfigs.html#override-default-configuration-properties

Comment: Oh God I completely missed it (face palm). Thank you man, thank you very much <3